# if 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation' filter hook return false, there is redirection, how prevent redirection?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use following filter hook to prevent add new product to cart if number of items in cart is 2. i.e. prevent add more than two items to cart.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'call_back_fn', 1, 3 );
function call_back_fn( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
   if( count(WC()->cart->get_cart()) >= 2 ){
     wc_add_notice( __( "cart item limitation", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
     $passed = false;
   }
   return $passed;
}
```

but when condition is true, when click 'add to cart' in shop page it redirects to that product single page and show notification. How prevent this and show notice in shop page?

Thanks

Comment: add is_shop() in your condition

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: when i did some tests if( is_shop() && count(WC()->cart->get_cart()) >= 2 ) {$passed = false} its not redirecting but u have to trigger reload and populate error or use ajax to show error .